# How to build filter so contract invoice lines product dropdown shows sellable products only

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using contracts in Odoo. In a contract I checked `generate recurring invoices`, and then I can add products for generating invoice lines.

If I add a product, there is a search dropdown for the product, but it shows items that may not be sold.

I want to fix that, so I searched the views and found it in `addons/./account_analytic_analysis/account_analytic_analysis_view.xml`. Here is the relevant xml:

```
   <div attrs="{'invisible': [('recurring_invoices','=',False)]}">
        <field name="recurring_invoice_line_ids">
            <tree string="Account Analytic Lines" editable="bottom">
                <field name="product_id" on_change="product_id_change(product_id, uom_id, quantity, False, parent.partner_id, False, parent.pricelist_id, parent.company_id)"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="quantity"/>
                <field name="uom_id"/>
                <field name="price_unit"/>
                <field name="price_subtotal"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </div>
```

To filter out the non-sellable products I wanted to add a filter_domain like so:

```
<field name="product_id"  
       filter_domain="[('product_id.product_tmpl_id.sale_ok','=',True)]"
       on_change="product_id_change(product_id, uom_id, quantity, False, parent.partner_id, False, parent.pricelist_id, parent.company_id)"
/>
```

actually I tried multiple forms of this, but nothing works, the non-sellable items are still listed. How do I build a correct filter?

Comment: use domain="[('product_id.product_tmpl_id.sale_ok','=',True)]"

Comment: Ok, tried that, now I get: `ValueError: Invalid field 'product_id.product_tmpl_id.sale_ok' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_id.product_tmpl_id.sale_ok', '=', True) on product_product (ctx: )>"`. That a new error, and I seem to come closer to the solution, but not solved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `<field name="product_id" .../>` add attribute `domain="[('sale_ok', '=', True)]"`

Comment: This works. Thanks! Though I do not understand, how a field (sale_ok) that is in product_template model, can be referenced just like that.

Comment: Your edit was fast :-P Yes product.product is inheriting product.template by delegation, so you can use the template fields directly.

Comment: What does 'by delegation' actually mean? In the database I see a field product_tmpl_id that points to the parent template. That is not a PostgreSQL term. Is 'delegation' in this respect an ORM term, or is it Odoo?

Comment: For further information see: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension